# Data grid view values change

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

How to check that data grid view values have changed pro grammatically in c sharp? I want to show a desktop alert on some change in data grid

Comment: what is the target deployment platform? web or desktop? If the target platform is web, how will you show alerts?

Comment: it is a desktop application.. the main issue is just finding out the change in the grid view...

Answer (score 0):

Check the `RowState` of  `DataTable` form `DataGridView` like this:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
DataTable modifiedRows = dt.GetChanges( DataRowState.Modified);
DataTable addedRows = dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
DataTable deletedRows = dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
```